# Heating system cycling

Tags: hvac, heating

My heating system is power cycling because the heat exhaust temperature sensor is tripping. When I turn the intake gas valve closed a bit, the system will stay on for longer but it's still does some cycling. Is it possible somebody installed an incorrect sensor in the exhaust area of my heating system?

The exhaust fan is on, I can see it's spinning.

Comment: Hello, and welcome to Home Improvement. What make/model is the unit, and is it hydronic or forced-air? Is this a new thing, and if so what changed? And, you should probably [take our tour](//diy.stackexchange.com/tour) so you'll know how best to participate here.

Comment: Did it just start doing this? A dirty filter can limit the airflow in the heat exchanger and cause excess heat.

Comment: It's always been doing this since I moved into this place. Originally the cycles were under 4 minutes but now they'll last much longer. It seems weird to me that the exhaust sensor is tripping. Plenty of air blows through the system and this happens even if there is no filter in place, let alone a new filter.